# Stitch grid of 375x375 images together into one

Tags: java, image, image-processing

I have a map, divided into 375x375 tiles of 16 pixels. I want to develop a java application to stitch those images together into one big image. How would I go about doing this in java? Any useful libraries?

Comment: Yes, [the JDK](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/imageio/index.html).

Comment: Is this for realtime rendering, e.g. in a game?

Comment: No, its for running on a high-powered server

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Create a `BufferedImage` that is 375*16 or 6000x6000px.  For a 36 MPix image, you will need a ***lot*** of memory.
2. Get a `Graphics` instance from the image.
3. Loop through the tiles and call `g.drawImage(tile, x, y)`
4. Dispose of the graphics instance.

Of course, it might make more sense (and would take a lot less memory) to draw the tiles that are within view, directly to the rendering surface of the game (if that is the end purpose).

> Any useful libraries?

Overkill for this.  Using either technique outlined above, it would only take a couple of lines of code.

Comment: Thank you! I will try this out. I don't think memory will be a problem, as it will be executed in a server environment.